# Any way to make cross-realm logins case insensitive?

Tags: windows, authentication, kerberos

I've got a demo [cross-realm](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/kerberos-interoperability-step-by-step-guide-for-windows-server-2003.aspx) setup between MIT Kerberos and AD. Users can log in just fine as long as the machine is properly configured and the user knows that the realm is all uppercase and case sensitive. I have a feeling though, that once we roll this out to the users, quite a few will remember this, even if we go through above normal outreach. Is there any way to make the Windows 7 login screen more usable? Like automatically uppercase the realm? Or automatically default to our Kerberos realm for user auth?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set the default via group policy for AD 2008.
Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\System\Logon "Assign a default domain for logon"

This works for kerberos realms.
This works for windows 7.
This does not work for Vista.
This does not work for XP.

Otherwise
regkey "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon\DefaultDomainName"